# Problems including bower installs in layout.jade

Tags: angularjs, pug, bower, mean-stack

I am fairly new to the mean stack, and when I switch from importing angular from cdn to bower in layout.jade my app stopped working. I am getting a "ReferenceError: angular is not defined" and 404s for all the sources I am trying to import.

This is how my layout.jade looks(I also tried ../ and ../../ in front, but got the same results):

```js
doctype html
html(ng-app='RIThym')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='bower_components/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js')
    script(src='bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    script(src='bower_components/angular-ui-map/ui-map.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/RIThym.js')
  body
    block content
```

This is my project structure:

> bin
>
> bower_components
>
> node_modules
>
> public
>
> routes
>
> views
>
> > layout.jade
>
> app.js
>
> package.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that public_html is root directory for your webserver. In that case server doesn't have access to bower_components  directory. And won't return anything from bower_components.

To solve this move bower_components directory to public_html.